# How to set AWS EC2 security group to allow SSH from all computers connected to 2 different home networks?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, ip

I have a Verizon router and a AT&T router at home and multiple computers that are connected to one of the two routers. I just started a free tier AWS EC2 Ubuntu server and would like to set its security group to allow SSH connection from all of my home computers. How do I do that?

(Currently it's just set to one computer of 11.22.33.44/32 where the numbers are made up.) I don't know how to customize the security group. I can add multiple rules.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to find out your *public IP* - websites like [ifconfig.co](https://ifconfig.co) or [whatismyip.com](https://whatismyip.com) will tell you. Then put that IP into your security group.